# Vectors that span $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, span

Just a quick check, I am asked to determine for which values of the parameter $k$ does this set of vectors $\{(-1, k, -1),\ (2, 2, 0),\ (1, k, 1)\}$ span $\mathbb{R}^3$.

My reasoning is that for them to span $\mathbb{R}^3$ they have to be linearly independent, therefore if we represent them as column vectors multiplied by some arbitrary scalars $c1$ - $c3$ respectively and add them together to equal the $0$ vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ we should be able to determine if they are linearly independent or not by seeing if there aren't any non-trivial solutions to this system of equations.

Hope I'm right, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. And your reasoning is equivalent to find the value(s) of $k$ for which the determinant of the matrix that has as columns the three vectors is not null. Do you see why?

Comment: Because if the determinant is 0 then it would mean that the vectors which are making up the columns of the matrix are linearly dependent? Also does this mean that these vectors are a basis for R^3 given that they span R^3 and that they are linearly independent?

Comment: Yes! all right! :)

Comment: Sorry, I edited the comment before, adding another question, do you mind ? Thank you so much  ! :)

Comment: Yes, if they are linearly independent than they form a basis.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this directly: any vector in R^3 is of the form .  The set {<-1, k, -1>, <2, 2, 0>, <1, k, 1>} span R^3 if and only if there exist numbers, a, b, c, such that = a<-1, k, -1>+ b<2, 2, 0>+ c<1, k, 1>= <-a+ 2b+ c, ka+ 2b+ kc, -a+ c>.  So we have the three equations -a+ 2b+ c= x, ka+ 2b+ kc= y, -a+ c= z.  Are there any values of k for which we **cannot** solve this for a, b, c given any x, y, z?  I notice that if we subtract the first equation from the second we eliminate b: (k+1)a+ (1-k)c= y- x  That, together with -a+ c= z give two equations to solve for a and c.  Multiplying the second equation by k+ 1 and adding that to the first equation eliminates a: (1-k)c+ (k+ 1)c= 2c= y- x+ (k+ 1)z so that for **any** k, we have c= (y- x+ (k+1)z)/2.  That can be solved for any value of k.